# Currency or Number in Process Builder formula

Tags: formula, process-builder

Getting an error when trying to display the currency or value of a field using the formula in Process builder. I need this to work for a callout.

Error

> Your changes are saved, but you can't activate this process until you
>   resolve the following errors. The formula expression is invalid:
>   Incorrect parameter type for operator '+'. Expected Text, received
>   Number

Formula:

```
"Annual Spend: " + VALUE(TEXT([Opportunity].Annual_Spend__c))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper operator for concatenation of strings is `&`, not `+`. Change the operator and your formula should become valid.

The correct formula should be:

```
"Annual Spend: " & TEXT([Opportunity].Annual_Spend__c)
```